# Trim Values existing in Mongo Database

Tags: c#, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

The data in my collection may have white spaces in the front and at the back what I want to do is trim all white spaces and make a == comparison to get the appropriate record my code below:

```
var test = await _dataStore.FindMostRecentAsync(x => x.Barcodes.PrimaryBarcode.Trim() == barcode.Trim());
```

When I run this code it gives me an error `.Trim()` not supported (it works only when I trim the barcode string variable that I pass in.

What is the best way to trim the data in my collection so I can have an exact comparison.

Stack Trace

> at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.GetFieldExpression(Expression
>   expression)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(Expression
>   variableExpression, ExpressionType operatorType, ConstantExpression
>   constantExpression)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression
>   node)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression
>   node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateFindOperation[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1
>   filter, FindOptions`2 options)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindAsync[TProjection](IClientSessionHandle
>   session, FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass37_0`1.b__0(IClientSessionHandle
>   session)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2
>   funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the aggregate function to be able to call the [trim operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/).

Sadly there is no direct way of calling through the C# driver however you can build one using some BsonDocuments like so:

```
var barcode = "     1512356      ";


//This exclude the trimmedField from the result.
var projectionDefinition = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("trimmedField");  
//Call the trim operator and put it in the temporary trimmedField property (this trims the barcode on the database)
var expression = new BsonDocument(new List<BsonElement>
    {
        new BsonElement("trimmedField", new BsonDocument(new BsonDocument("$trim", new BsonDocument("input", "$Barcodes.PrimaryBarcode"))))
    });

//Add the trimmedField to the document
var addFieldsStage = new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("$addFields", expression));

//Build a filter on the trimmedField and trim the local variable
var trimFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(x => x["trimmedField"], barcode.Trim());

//Put it all together
var result = collection.Aggregate().AppendStage<BsonDocument>(addFieldsStage).Match(trimFilter).Project(projectionDefinition).As<YourType>().ToList();
```

Make sure to put the correct Type in the `.As<T>` to be able to cast the entity.

And if you add `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` above your class you'll be able to drop the projection stage.

Comment: Wow, I cant believe all this has to be done in order to pas in the Trim() in the agg statement, I am guessing eventually they will implement this as a direct call. Thank you for your answer I think people will find value in it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up for this was to do the following:

```
var test = await _dataStore.FindMostRecentAsync(x => x.Barcodes.PrimaryBarcode.Contains(barcode.Trim()));
```

Instead of trying to trim the values that existed in the database I will trim the variable and then do a Contains that way I will get all the values that match my barcode, later on with that array of objects I can go ahead and filter by date or what not.

I have not found any way in which we can pass in the Trim() method for the collection object using the C# MongoDriver