# Trim() & ToLower() in mongo C# driver

Tags: c#, .net, database, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have this scenario:

```
var filterDefinition = Builders<CustomModel>.Filter.Eq(x => x.CustomModelPropertyField.Trim().ToLower(), customParameterValue.Trim().ToLower());

await Collection.Find(filterDefinition).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The problem is when I am using Trim() and/or ToLower() inside the filterDefinition, it's throwing exceptions.
From what I understood, mongo c# driver does not support this kind of extentions like Trim or ToLower but there is any other method to rewrite this one so mongo can accept it ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do people always keep the exceptions secret? You'd think that between the exception and their code, the exception would be the least secret part.

Comment: MongoDB seems to support case-insensitive indexes now, and before then the solution was to use a regex query. That would get rid of your `ToLower` hack (in a much better way: some locales don't round-trip between upper-case and lower-case)

Comment: try this `x => x.CustomModelPropertyField?.Trim().ToLower()`. `CustomModelPropertyField` can be `null`

Comment: you can use regex and use /i paramter to ignore case, see the following answere
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058061/c-sharp-mongodb-case-sensitive-search

Comment: @MichaelGabbay that url helped me for the case problem, but the trim problem still persist. It seems that trim() is not supported as part of Linq syntax in mongo c# driver but Ihave tried to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385339/trim-values-existing-in-mongo-database

Comment: @Llama I haven't added the stacktrace because i specified in description that "mongo c# driver does not support this kind of extensions like Trim or ToLower" and I thought that should be enough.